# How can I redirect website.com/en to website.com/en/ in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, routes

We have this in routes.rb for localization:

```
scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/, defaults: {locale: 'nl'} do
     get '/', to: 'home_student#index'
     ...
end
```

I tried:

`get '/en', to: redirect('/en/')`

Comment: Just making sure I understand, the importance of having the trailing slash here is so that child URLs go to `website.com/en/child_path` instead of `website.com/child_path` ?

Comment: Why do you need that redirect? What is the issue or error message without such a redirect?